# ¿Cómo ejecuto correctamente un Stored Procedure desde un cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, sql-server-2012

Buenas a todos, estoy teniendo problemas para ejecutar un SP de SQL Server.

El SP tiene una opción que arma un SQL dinámico y lo ejecuta retornando un valor

```
    SET @campo = (SELECT 
                        CC.Campo
                    FROM 
                        ConfigPendientes AS CP
                            INNER JOIN ConfigCampos AS CC on CC.Id_CC = CP.Id_Campo 
                            INNER JOIN Pendientes AS PEN ON PEN.Id_SP = CP.Id_CP
                    WHERE 
                        CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CP.Id_CP) LIKE @Id_SP AND
                        CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PEN.Id_Pendiente) LIKE @Id_Pendiente
                    )
    SET @tabla = (SELECT 
                        CT.Nombre_Tabla
                    FROM 
                        ConfigPendientes AS CP
                            INNER JOIN ConfigCampos AS CC on CC.Id_CC = CP.Id_Campo 
                            INNER JOIN ConfigTablas AS CT on CT.Id_Tabla = CC.Id_Tabla
                            INNER JOIN Pendientes AS PEN ON PEN.Id_SP = CP.Id_CP
                    WHERE 
                        CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CP.Id_CP) LIKE @Id_SP AND
                        CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PEN.Id_Pendiente) LIKE @Id_Pendiente
                    )
    SET @cond = (SELECT 
                        CC.Campo
                    FROM 
                        ConfigPendientes AS CP
                            INNER JOIN ConfigCampos AS CC on CC.Id_CC = CP.Id_CampoFiltrar 
                            INNER JOIN Pendientes AS PEN ON PEN.Id_SP = CP.Id_CP
                    WHERE 
                        CONVERT(NVARCHAR, CP.Id_CP) LIKE @Id_SP AND
                        CONVERT(NVARCHAR, PEN.Id_Pendiente) LIKE @Id_Pendiente
                    )
    SET @busq = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @IdElemento)
    SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + @campo + ' from ' + @tabla + ' where ' + @cond + ' = ' + @busq

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql
```

y si yo le paso los valores manualmente, funciona como yo quiero.

El problema esta en que necesito que desde el SP_X se ejecute el SP_X con un @Opcion distinto (esta variable es la que determina que consulta ejecutar) que yo le voy a indicar, y este SP_X se debe ejecutar desde un cursor que va a ir insertando la información en una tabla temporal. (No sé si me he hecho entender)

```
OPEN #CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM #CURSOR INTO @IdCP, @IdPen, @IdEle, @IdUsu
    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
        BEGIN
            EXEC @Valor = SP_EXECUTESQL SP_X, @Id_Pendiente = @IdPen, @Id_SP = @IdCP, @IdElemento = @IdEle, @Opcion = 1002
            INSERT INTO #temp VALUES (@IdPen, @IdCP, @IdEle, @Valor, @IdUsu, 1)
            FETCH NEXT FROM #CURSOR INTO @IdCP, @IdPen, @IdEle, @IdUsu
        END
    CLOSE #CURSOR
```

el problema es que siempre me manda este error

> Mens. 102, Nivel 15, Estado 1, Línea 1
>   Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de '1'.

En lo poco que pude deducir, es que el número que retorna en el mensaje de error es el valor de la variable *@IdPen*.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno, la solución a mi problema fue crear una tabla aparte para almacenar el resultado del SP y luego hacer un inner join para poder mostrarlo.

Comment: Sugeriría mostrar un código de ejemplo y luego, que marques tu respuesta como aceptada :)

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, realmente no recuerdo exactamente el código porque ya fue hace mucho tiempo y tampoco tengo acceso a dichos procedimientos almacenados. 

Pero viendo lo que comenté como solución, creo que hice una consulta que tuviese un id relacional entre ambos resultados de tal manera que hayan 2 columnas en la tabla #tempB para poder hacer un inner join con la tabla #temp. Tal vez no fue la solución más óptima, pero hizo su trabajo cuando lo necesité.